# Value always null for setter

Tags: c#, properties, field, getter-setter, accessor

I have the Class below. The Coach property is used as the accessor for the coach field. It checks if there is an existing "Club" value, and assigns the "Coach" to this "Club" if there is none.

```
public class Club
    {
        private Coach coach;

        public Coach Coach
        {
            get
            {
                return coach;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value.Club != null)
                {
                    coach = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    coach = null;
                }
                 
            }
        }
```

In my driver class, I have something like the code below to assign the coach to a club. However, when I run this, the value would always be null and I can't seem to properly assign a value to the "coach" field through the Coach accessor.

```
private static void AssignCoach(Club club1, Coach coach1)
{
 club1.Coach = coach1;
}

AssignCoach(club1, coach1);
```

Comment: This question doesn't provide enough information for us to debug the problem. Please provide a [mcve]. At a guess, your `if` statement condition isn't being satisfied.

Comment: your code as shown will work fine, my guess is other code you have is getting confused because you have a circular reference with coach and club

Comment: Try assigning a coach that already has a club and you will see your error ;)

Answer (score 1):

This specification:

> It checks if there is an existing "Club" value, and assigns the "Coach" to this "Club" if there is none.

Is not implemented by this code:

```
                if (value.Club != null)
                {
                    coach = value;
                }
```

The code means "if the passed in coach **already has a club**, make them a coach of this club"

The specification reads as "if the passed in coach **does not have** a club, make them a coach of this club"